# SharePoint 2013 Content Databases limit

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Is 500 content databases a limit or just a performance threshold? I mean, does SharePoint block us to create more than 500 DBs or is it just not recommended?

Comment: It's not recommended and likely won't be supported if you try to escalate to Microsoft. But it won't wont you from doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this Technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx), the number of content databases per farm represents a “Supported limit”. The definition of “Supported limit” reads:

> Supported limits define the tested value for a given parameter. The default values for these limits were defined by testing, and represent the known limitations of the product. Exceeding supported limits may cause unexpected results, significant decrease in performance, or other harmful effects.

So, you *can* create more than 500 content databases, *but* it's likely the farm will tend to be poorly manageable or you can observe other adverse effects.

---

*Note: The article referenced above is relevant for SharePoint 2013, i.e. the version specified in the question's tags. However, in SharePoint 2016 the situation [is the same](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.16).aspx).*